# Using values from wordpress theme-options in css

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I would like to set my styling-colors of my wordpress-theme with theme-options. My problem is, how do I get the color-value of theme options into my css? I know where the theme-options values are stored, but how can I connect this with my css?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Use PHP to write a CSS file every time theme options change (a CSS cache).

   You can also take advantage of CSS preprocessors like [Less](http://lesscss.org/) or Sass, which compile the CSS for you.

   Sample code, assuming you are using the WP options API:

   ```
   $theme_options = get_option('my_theme_options');

   // previous hash
   $oldHash = get_transient('my_theme_options_hash');

   // hash representation of your current theme options
   $currentHash = md5(var_export($theme_options, true));

   // compare hashes and regenerate if necessary
   if($oldHash !== $currentHash){

     // compile/write your CSS to a file here

     // update hash and make it expire after 14 days
     set_transient('my_theme_options_hash', $currentHash, 60 * 60 * 24 * 14);
   }
   ```
2. Put inline CSS code in your theme header:

   ```
   <style>
     <![CDATA[]]>
      body{ 
        background-color: <?= get_option('my_theme_color'); ?>; 
      }
     ]]>
   </style>
   ```
3. *(Worst possible option)* Turn your stylesheet into a PHP script that outputs `text/css`. This is bad because you're forcing your server run WordPress twice for every user page request. You could call a script that only loads basic WP components, but it's still going to be slower than using a static CSS

Comment: Thank you. I have used the 2. otion and its working....

Comment: @onetrickpony Do you have any links or resources about option 1 (php script that writes a CSS file every theme options change)?  I'm finding a lot of info about CSS preprocessors but I want a simple method of recompiling the CSS *only* when theme options change and not adding another PHP call for every page load.

Comment: @nextgentech: I've added some code that might help you understand how to do this

Answer (score 2):

This is a great question.

NetTuts has tutorial that explains the method of fooling the browser to interpret a CSS file as PHP, therefore you could use PHP inside CSS and load color variables for example.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-add-variables-to-your-css-files/

And you will be able to use something like this:

```
$font: arial, sans-serif;  
$main-color: #3D7169; $secondary-color: #000;  
h1 {  
    font: 200% $font;  
    color: $main-color;  
}  
p {  
    background: $secondary-color;  
    color: $main-color;  
    font-family: $font;  
    padding: 10px;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have dynamic css by changing Style.css to Style.php.

If you are questioning is it possible ?

**Yes** it is, [here](http://thejimgaudet.com/articles/support/web/dynamic-css-changing-style-css-to-style-php/) is the good reference that will show you how & what are the other benefits of using it & how to use it.